# Moving array from jQuery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to transfer an array from jQuery to PHP but for some reason after hours of searching nothing will work. Below is what I have and what others seem to be using online but for some reason I only get the error alert. Anyone know what it is I'm doing wrong? It seems to be something to do with my jQuery code but I can put in anything there and get the same results so it is useless for telling me what I am supposed to fix. Also Im not sure if it is important but the array Im using is 2d.
FINAL WORKING CODE:
jQuery:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "phpfile.php",
        data: {"myData" : myArray},
        success: function(data){
            alert("Success");
            //appends code to end of my webpage, just for testing purposes
            $('#button').after(data);
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert("Error")
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
$data = $_POST['myData'];
//creates xml file
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: You don't need to stringify simple arrays, jquery will correctly parameterize it and php will correctly convert it back to an array. However, **your code should work as-is.** (assuming your php returns json)

Comment: Check your network tab. What call is being sent? What's being received? Are you actually **returning** `json` from the PHP? (otherwise it'll fail as you specified `dataType: "json"`).

Comment: When I print e.message to the console (instead of alert("error")) it says "undefined".
I tried this way and also by just passing the array into data:, both end up the same.
Nothing seems to be being sent.

Comment: @Shrui In Chrome you have a Tab such as `console` which is called `Network`. There you can see your Request and you'll have a tab `Request` and `Response`. Use that to see waht is going wrong

Comment: Is your url name correct? I would make sure the filename is all lower case and make the code url: "phpfile.php" and see if that helps.

Comment: @Shrui Since you didn't answer; Does your PHP script return JSON? It **has** to return JSON when you use `dataType: "json"`.

Comment: @AndreschSerj Im using Firefox but found the network tab there, it isn't showing anything being sent or received except for a GET for a javascript library I kept in my code.

Comment: @rrtx2000 tried that, no difference.

Comment: @h2ooooooo originally it wasnt but I have included it now. Didnt make a difference. I will update the code in the question now.

Comment: It seems like it should be working so I would try a simple, very basic ajax test and make sure at least that is working correctly. I would try to: 1) Get rid of the dataType json line. 2) Take the "/" out of the url. 3) Change the data to {"myData" : "testing"} or even get rid of the data line altogether. 4) Change the PHP to only be: echo "test". Then see if you alert Success. This will hopefully tell you that your ajax is working. If so, you can start putting your code back in and see where it fails.

Comment: @rrtx2000 Tried what you said, it was the dataType:"json" line causing the issues. Had some more problems with stuff appearing as garbage and accessing values but using var_dump helped me work it out and now it appears to be working perfectly. Thanks for the help, sadly I dont have enough reputation to upvote yet. I updated the code showing the final working code in case anyone else comes across it.

Comment: No problem. I copied my comment into an answer so you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is copied from the comment so this question can be marked as answered:

It seems like it should be working so I would try a simple, very basic ajax test and make sure at least that is working correctly. I would try to:

1) Get rid of the dataType json line.

2) Take the "/" out of the url.

3) Change the data to {"myData" : "testing"} or even get rid of the data line altogether.

4) Change the PHP to only be: echo "test".

Then see if you alert Success. This will hopefully tell you that your ajax is working. If so, you can start putting your code back in and see where it fails.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake might be:

```
data: {"myData" : myjsonString}
```

Try this, assumming that jsonString is a string

```
data: "myData="+ jsonString
```